# When does it matter whether you use int versus Int32, or string versus String?

Tags: c#, types

In C#, the keywords for [built-in types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ya5y69ds.aspx) are simply aliases for corresponding types in the `System` namespace.

Generally, it makes no difference whether you use a keyword (such as `int`) or an identifier (such as `Int32`) to refer to a built-in type. But there's an exception to everything, so my question in two parts is:

1. When does C# *require* you to use, or not use, a keyword?
2. When does using a keyword instead of an identifier change the meaning of the program?

Comment: I don't think this question is a duplicate of "C#, int or Int32? Should I care?" That other question asks why it might be preferable to use int instead of Int32. This question specifically asks about cases in which you *must* use int instead of Int32 (for example, in enums), or vice versa. The accepted answer to that question does not address this question.

Comment: Your first question is answered by the duplicated question.  Your second question is the wrong question, it makes no difference, unless one or the other is expected.  For example when you create an enum, it can only be a byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong.

Comment: @Ramhound: In what way is the second question a "wrong question"? The "unless one or the other is expected" is exactly what the OP is asking: in which situations *is* one or the other expected? Also, it's certainly possible to have situations where both are valid but they give different results.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I'm reopening, so please consider answering this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [using alias directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) *cannot* use a keyword as the type name (but *can* use keywords in type argument lists):

```
using Handle = int; // error
using Handle = Int32; // OK
using NullableHandle = Nullable<int>; // OK
```

The [underlying type of an enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx) *must* be specified using a keyword:

```
enum E : int { } // OK
enum E : Int32 { } // error
```

The expressions `(x)+y`, `(x)-y`, and `(x)*y` are interpreted differently depending on whether `x` is a keyword or an identifier:

```
(int)+y // cast +y (unary plus) to int
(Int32)+y // add y to Int32; error if Int32 is not a variable
(Int32)(+y) // cast +y to Int32

(int)-y // cast -y (unary minus) to int
(Int32)-y // subtract y from Int32; error if Int32 is not a variable
(Int32)(-y) // cast -y to Int32

(int)*y // cast *y (pointer indirection) to int
(Int32)*y // multiply Int32 by y; error if Int32 is not a variable
(Int32)(*y) // cast *y to Int32
```

Comment: Current C# allows enum E : Int32{}. No idea when it changed, but that code compiles fine in VS2019.

Answer (score 8):

C# doesn't require you to use one or the other as they are equivalent. It is a personal preference and coding convention. So use the one that seems more readable to you and your team. Just one advice: be consistent: do not use an alias in half of your codebase and the full type name in the second half.

Comment: Might also be worth being completely pedantic and to say that absent a `using System;` directive, you would have to use the built-in shorthands or fully qualify the types, as in `System.String val;` The shorthands work independently of using directives or full qualification, as they are built into the language.

Answer (score 2):

`string` is an alias for the type `System.String`, and `int` is an alias for `System.Int32`.  Therefore, use to your preference.

Answer (score 1):

The identifiers `int`, `string`, `bool`, etc. are C# language aliases for the real types `Int32`, `String`, and `Boolean`, respectively. It doesn't matter which you use, but when you're writing an API some people prefer to use the actual class types to the aliases.

Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) that lists the equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. `int` is basically a shorthand for `System.Int32` they are almost perfectly interchangable. Consider it a #define if you like (but C# doesn't allow #defines like that).

Comment: They're not perfectly interchangable. Try declaring an enum as `enum Foo : Int32 {}` for example.

Comment: @JonSkeet added fuzzy modifier

Answer (score 0):

One issue is that with strange `using`s or member declarations `String`/`Int32` can map to a different type(i.e. not the one from mscorlib) or even another kind of member, which would lead to problems.

As Jon mentioned, another issue is that you can't declare enums using an identifier(You get the error "Type byte, sbyte, short, ushort, int, uint, long, or ulong expected").

Comment: As noted on other answers: there *is* a difference for enum declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require you to use one or the other.  However, if you want a larger or smaller int you might want to explicitly use Int16 or Int64 instead of int which is an alias for Int32.

Comment: Not sure where your example is going - why would you not use `short` or `long`? However, C# *does* require you to use the keyword when declaring enums.

Comment: Actually, that's a good point.  Alias's exist for Int16 and Int64 as well so I guess it's really up to the developer which to use.

Answer (score 0):

The only situation I can think of in which you are *required* to use the aliases in a form where you might otherwise be able to use a class name is in the definition of enum types:

```
public enum MyEnum:Byte //will not compile

public enum MyEnum:byte //correct
```

Notice also that the definition of an enum requires use of the alias keyword, while when defining code members that can accept any enumerated type, you use the class name Enum.

Lastly, you can never specify `System.ValueType` as a base class or generic type parameter; you instead use the `struct` keyword, which is essentially an alias for an object deriving from ValueType.