# is string and String same?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the difference between String and string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)
>   [When does it matter whether you use int versus Int32, or string versus String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8747190/when-does-it-matter-whether-you-use-int-versus-int32-or-string-versus-string)

in visual studio when i am typing string,it shows two suggestions as

[image: the screenshot]

is both 'string' and 'String' same? Visual studio shows the same description for both.

so if they are same what is the need for keeping two different things which perform the same function?

Comment: left click on both and go to definition you wont see any difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah there is technically no difference at all with your use of it, as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string) article confirms. As said in the answer, it is considered best practice if you use `string`.

Hope this clears it up for you!

Comment: This is also the option recommended by StyleCop

Answer (score 4):

`string` is nothing more than an alias for `System.String`.

The same holds for `int` being an alias for `System.Int32` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7074/whats-the-difference-between-string-and-string)).

I also agree with the general guideline of using `String` for static function calls such as `String.Format` rather than `string.Format` (although I prefer `string.Empty`), and using `string` for objects (`string hello = "world";`).

But, at this point, it's all a matter of preferences and conventions.

Comment: I would like to point out to the OP that I posted that link and the content from it first

Comment: I Googled it, didn't just steal it (just to clarify).

Comment: Sorry, didnt mean to imply that, just meant to say that I did post it first, thats all.

Answer (score 2):

Also [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx) says the same, `string` is just an alias for `System.String`. If you want to see a full map of types that are aliased in C#, you can refer here: [Data Types (C# vs. Java)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228360%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are. `string` is just an alias of `String`: they have the same features and they work the same way... normally I prefer to use String because of the code synthax highlight. But they are equivalent, exactly like `int` is an alias of `Int32` and `long` is an alias of `Int64`.

Comment: I preferr string, but mainly because thats the version StlyeCop demands.

Answer (score 0):

I think both are same things, because both in the same namespace. So don't get confused. You can use any of them for string representation.